# How do I remove elements with xuijs?

Tags: javascript, mobile, xui

I have:

```
<div class="result">
  <div class="child">
    <h2>afsdf</h2>
    <p>ardyh</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h2>....
  ..
  </div>
</div>
```

and want to replace all in .result with

```
<p>please wait..</p>
```

$x('.result').html('remove') does nothing and no method of .html removes the children.

How to to it?

regards,
/t

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x$` and not `$x`?  Have you gotten anything to work?  Are there errors on the console?

Comment: xuijs doesn't have anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: yes, that's a typo. ok in original code. Much works, no errors in firebug.

Comment: @mblase75, you're right, xuijs didn't even exist as a tag so..

Comment: besides h2 and p, there's a div for every child, does that makes any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x$('.result').html('<p>please wait..</p>');
```

should work according to the documentation of xuijs

Comment: tried it over and over. it inserts the text on start of .result, leaving all children as it is, :-(

Comment: what about : `x$('.result').html('inner', '<p>please wait..</p>');` ?

Comment: and if you write `<div id="result">` and simply try to change it like that : `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML('<p>please wait..</p>')`

Comment: Forgive me, old content reloded through ajax. My errror. Thanks for your involvment.

Answer (score 0):

x$('#foo').html('remove');

http://xuijs.com/docs/dom